# Problem with launching webpage at boot

Tags: boot, systemd, services, web

I am facing some issues starting a webpage with my raspberry pi at boot. I created a web weather dashboard with some widgets and I want my raspberry pi to start this webpage at boot.

My raspberry has an embed screen (RPI from my school don't know which screen it is) and while using VNC the webpage launches but not on the screen. I am getting this:

```
Firefox is already running, but it is not responding.
```

In the autostart file I have already tried to kill firefox process and then launch the page but nothing works.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting programs on boot up is managed by **systemd** using services. So you can create a new service with a unit file that starts the internet browser with the webpage addressed. Here you can look [how to start the internet browser on startup](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/109456/79866).

Comment: Okay I did not caught the difference. It worked thank you very much !

Comment: @Julien "accept" this answer if it has helped you or add a new answer to explain how it has solved.