# simple way to open webbrowser in fullscreen from python script

Tags: raspbian, boot, pi-4, web-browsers

I want to open my chromium web browser in fullscreen-mode and open an URL that I get from a different config file. All this should happen automatically after booting. 
For testing, I tried to execute a terminal command in python first of all with

```
import os
import webbrowser
os.system(chromium-browser --start-fullscreen www.google.de)
```

But it throws an invalid syntax error.

Is there a possibility to start the browser with something different than with a systemd service file?

I am running this on an RPI 4 with the newest version of Raspbian.
Thank you for your advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the service as per the other answer as [os.system()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) is no longer the preferred way of [calling external programs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess-replacements).

If you do wish to put the command into a python program using os.system() then you could use:

```
import os
cmd = "/usr/bin/chromium-browser --start-fullscreen www.google.de"
os.system(cmd)
```

The advantage of Python is that it is much simpler to handle error checks / reporting (code snippet - will not work fully):

```
try:
    retcode = call(cmd, shell=True)
    if retcode < 0:
        print("Browser was terminated", -retcode, file=sys.stderr)
    else:
        print("Browser returned", retcode, file=sys.stderr)
except OSError as e:
    print("Execution of the browser failed:", e, file=sys.stderr)
```

Note the use of sys.stderr to get the completion status back from the browser.

Answer (score 2):

Create a service file:

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/startupbrowser.service
```

Put all lines below there:

```
[Unit]
Description=startupbrowser
After=graphical.target

[Service]
User=pi
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
ExecStart=/usr/bin/chromium-browser --start-fullscreen www.google.de

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

Enable the new service and reboot the raspberry pi:

```
sudo systemctl enable startupbrowser.service 
sudo systemctl reboot
```

---

*[Source](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/109419/execute-python-file-on-systemstart)*

Comment: Better not to fiddle direct with systemd system files in `/etc/systemd/system/`. It is less error prone using `systemctl edit` with its options, in particular if you have drop in files.