# Kiosk GUI not appear after boot

Tags: gui, kiosk, python-2.x

I wrote a python GTK Kiosk program for the Raspberry pi and when I execute it from terminal it works properly. I want to run it automatically after booting and I tried several ways to do that (.bashrc, rc.local y systemd) and the program starts but the window not appear. I know that the program is running because it is on task manager but there is no way to see the GUI. There is a way to make it appear on boot?? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

If it runs on the command line you can use a **systemd** Unit file to define exactly the same environment you have on the command line. You can find some examples here on the site how to do it. One example to start the chromium browser you can find at [execute Python file on Systemstart](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/109456/79866). Just modify the line `ExecStart=` in the Unit file to call your kiosk program like do you do it on the command line.

If it does not run on the first attempt then I need some more information about your special environment so we can modify the Unit to fit it.

Comment: I already created the daemon but when I check the status it is running but the window never appeared. I also tried using cron and @reboot but the same result.

Comment: @JorgeEnrique What is the name of your systemd service that starts the Kiosk program? I mean the Unit file that contains the line `ExecStart=...`?